# Is there a way to export QGIS layers to KML?

Tags: qgis, kml, qgis-plugins

has had anyone had any luck with the new experimental plugin qgis2kml?
 I keep getting the error msg  **layer : format not yet supported**

I had a look but the author has not provided any documentation, although I can't access the author's homepage at the moment. 
I tried different projections, but other parts of the error message refer to symbology.

Comment: seem it only supports points currently - QGIS will export to KML (no plugin) via 'Save as' by right clicking on the layer (select Format KML)

Comment: What are you trying to save? Points, lines or polygons? Just geometries or styles too?

Comment: A combination of points and polygons. Yes the styles are the target, simple stuff. Labels on point polygons and lines would be ideal.

Comment: OK, I accept that it is not common to display labels on polygons in GE. My interest in qgis2kml remains.

Comment: There was already a nice plugin to transfer features (with symbology) from QGIS to Google http://gis-lab.info/qa/qgis2google-eng.html written in C++ but unfortunately never merged into QGIS core code and so quickly stopped to work. It would be really nice if someone would be able to step in and support its porting in python (or support its debugging and merging into QGIS core).

Answer (score 1):

PlanetGIS has always been easiest for me when I want to export files as KML.  You can download a trial version of PlanetGIS here:
http://www.planetgis.co.za/
Once you have installed PlanetGIS and opened a .shp, go File---> Export ----> Select the file you want to export, then select the destination folder and name it (remember to select KML or KMZ from the dropdown menu).  You then have the option of exporting the file as a single placemark or with attributes.  Unfortunately, if you select only some of the attributes, it exports all of them anyway.  It also allows you to select a display label, which is useful.

Comment: Have you tried ossimPlanet?
It has a kmlsuperoverlay plugin http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/kmlsuperoverlayplugin

You can read your data in ossimplanet and export as kmz files for visualizing in ossimplanet see ossimPlanet here - http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/OssimPlanet

Answer (score 1):

You can install [gearthview](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/gearthview/) plugin (note that you also have to install Google Earth). From there you can click on "Qgis view" => "Save place as".